# what are the necessary steps to be keep in mind, if anybody wants to convert Normal WPF project to MVVM enabled one?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

If anybody wants to convert a Normal WPF project to MVVM enabled one,
what are the main points to be keep in mind while restructuring the entire application.
What are the main hurdles to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Separate all presentation logic in view model, buisness logic in model, keep view without codebehind(sometimes not possible) ?